# Typescript enruta un archivo externo correctamente pero luego en JS no coincide la ruta base para encontrarlo

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

Resulta que estaba programando alegremente en Typescript con Electron, funcionando todo a las mil maravillas, y en algún momento decidí separar parte del código en una librería externa.
Así que ahora tengo dos archivos TS en la misma carpeta:

`renderer.ts` (archivo "principal")
`isolib.ts` (archivo externo)

La forma que tengo de llamar a `isolib.ts` desde `renderer.ts` es la siguiente:

```
import * as ISO from './isolib'
```

que en el archivo .JS compilado termina siendo un:

```
var ISO = require('./isolib');
```

El problema viene cuando al ejecutar el código JS compilado, obtengo un bonito `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './isolib'`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi teoría es que Typescript compila con una ruta base determinada, y luego en JS la ruta es distinta al hacer el `require`.
Es decir `"./isolib"` es una cosa en el archivo .TS, y luego es otra distinta en el archivo .JS

¿Cómo he llegado a esta conclusión?

Pues porque poniendo la **RUTA ABSOLUTA** del archivo en el archivo .TS con la fórmula `require` de JS, **funciona perfectamente**,

es decir, en lugar de poner en mi .TS esto:

```
import * as ISO from './isolib'
```

pongo esto:

```
const ISO = require('d:/proyectos/Electron JS/Adso Game/dist/isolib')
```

Y así consigo que funcione. Pero supongo que habrá una forma de arreglarlo más allá de esto.

Este es mi **tsconfig.json** por si sirve de algo:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {"*": ["node_modules/*"]}
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*" ]
}
```

Seguramente he tocado algo, o cambiado alguna opción, o path o lo que sea, pero ya no sé que trastear más.

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.